# Вывод числа с запятыми

Tags: c#

От руки натыкав или считая количество строк из тхт, софт мне показывает какое-то число,  к примеру `2937758` (рандомно набрал)- столько строк. А как быть, чтобы он кроме цифр показывал запятые после каждого 3-го числа типа чтобы вывод был, как был и еще вот так: `2,937,758` ? Можно еще добавить слова, 2 милиона ну итд..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[String.Format()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
int value = 1234567890;
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:0,0}", value));
```

Выведет: 1,234,567,890